# Ring theory clarification

Tags: ring-theory

Say I have a ring $R=\{a+b\sqrt{3}|~ a,~,b\in\mathbf{Z}\}$.
And for all p,c,b that belong in R where p is not the additive zero. We have that p=pcb ,could I just cancel the p and say that cb=1 or do I have to say that p-pcb=0 so p(1-cb)=0 that is 1-cb=0?
Also it would be great if I could get a general answer to any ring aswell.
Thanks

Comment: Neither of those is correct.  In a ring we do not in general have "multiplicative inverses" but we may have "zero divisors".  That is, in a general ring, xy= 0 does NOT necessarily imply "x= 0 or y= 0"  An example is the ring of integer "modulo 6".  2*3= 6= 0 (mod 6) but neither 2 nor 3 is 0.

Comment: but in the ring $\mathbb Z + \mathbb Z \sqrt 3$ considered here, which is the subring of a field, there aren't non-zero zero divisors

Comment: if a ring is a domain (i.e., it has no non-zero zero divisors), then it has the cancellation property (you may cancel $p$ if $p\ne0$)

Comment: Hmm I see guys, thing is I haven’t been taught the domain part of rings but I see what you’re saying . Thanks all

Comment: Domains are special rings that don't have non-zero zero divisors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general ring, we cannot say that ${p\ne0}$ and $p=pcb$ implies $1=cb$,

nor can we say  $p\ne0$ and $p(1-cb)=0$ implies $1=cb$.

For example, in $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ (integers modulo $6$), $2\not\equiv0$ and $2\equiv2\times2\times2$ but $1\not\equiv2\times2$,

and $2(1-2\times2)\equiv0$ but $1\not\equiv2\times2$.

But in a domain (ring without non-zero zero divisors), we can make those inferences.

In particular, every subring of a field is a domain; in particular $\mathbb Z + \mathbb Z \sqrt3$ is a domain,

so for $R=\mathbb Z + \mathbb Z \sqrt3$ we can make those inferences.